# How can I send BNB with metamask using web3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web3js

I want to receive Payment as bnb with metamask on my website. I am using web3 for this.
I couldn't find how to send bnb instead of Ethereum. my arm is like this
hello, I want to receive Payment as bnb with metamask on my website. I am using web3 for this.
I couldn't find how to send bnb instead of Ethereum. my arm is like this

```js
console.log(window.web3)
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })

    const initPayButton = () => {
      $('.pay-button').click(() => {
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = '0x192c96bfee59158441f26101b2db1af3b07feb40'
        const amountEth = 1

        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('Payment successful')
          }
        })
      })
    }
```

```css
console.log(window.web3)
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })

    const initPayButton = () => {
      $('.pay-button').click(() => {
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = '0x192c96bfee59158441f26101b2db1af3b07feb40'
        const amountEth = 1

        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('Payment successful')
          }
        })
      })
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button class="pay-button">Pay</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

BNB is not stored in the ethereum blockchain. It has its own blockchain called Binance chain (although previously it ran on ethereum blockchain). What the "Web3" object require, is something called the web3 provider to connect the a node of a certain blockchain. So assuming the payment address is of Binance chain mainnet, the web provider will be "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443", so that you can connect to Binance chain. So in the code it will be:

```
window.web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
```

Also, since you're using metamask might as well connect to the binance chain through metamask. To do so click the Netowrk dropdown -> "Custom RPC". Then add the binance network and save:

[image]

For more details you can check [here](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain).